# Find all possible solutions of the system of linear equations.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the system of linear equations:

$\hspace{20pt}6x_2 + 2x_3 + 10x_4 = b_1$

$x_1 +x_2+4x_3- 2x_4  \hspace{5pt}=b_2$

$x_1 - 2x_2 + 3x_3 - 7x_4 = b_3$

(a) Find all possible Values of $b_1$,$b_2$,and $b_3$ for which this system has solutions;

(b)Find all possible solutions of this system if $b_1=6$,$b_2=7$, and $b_3 = 4$.

I was able to solve (a), but not sure what the solution should look like for (b)?

I set up an augmented matrix obtain rref of the matrix:**(edit after comment)**

$\begin{bmatrix}
  0&6&2&10&b_1\\
  1&1&4&-2&b_2\\
  1&-2&3&-7&b_3\\
  \end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
                 1&0&\frac{11}{3}&-\frac{11}{3}&b_2-\frac{1}{6}b_1\\
                 0&1&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{5}{3}&\frac{1}{6}b_1\\
                 0&0&0&0&b_3-b_2+\frac{1}{2}b_1\\
                            \end{bmatrix}$

So for (a): $b_2 = \frac{1}{6}b_1$; $b_3=b_2-\frac{1}{2}b_1=-\frac{1}{3}b_1$.

We get, $\begin{bmatrix}
         \frac{1}{6}b_1\\
         \frac{1}{6}b_1\\
         -\frac{1}{3}b_1
          \end{bmatrix}$ the column space of matrix is the line containing vector  $\begin{bmatrix}
         \frac{1}{6}\\
         \frac{1}{6}\\
         -\frac{1}{3}
          \end{bmatrix}$.

For part (b), the rank of the matrix is $2 +$ nullspace $= 4$ (number of columns). Thus $x_3$, and $x_4$ will be scalars so let $x_3=s$,$x_4=t$.

For given values of $b_1=6$,$b_2=7$,$b_3=4$ we have the augmented matrix:
\begin{bmatrix}
      1&0&\frac{11}{3}&-\frac{11}{3}&6\\
      0&1&\frac{1}{3}&\frac{5}{3}&1\\
       0&0&0&0&0\\
\end{bmatrix}

$\Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
         1\\
         0\\
         0
         \end{bmatrix}x_1+\begin{bmatrix}
         0\\
         1\\
         0
          \end{bmatrix}x_2+\begin{bmatrix}
         \frac{1}{3}\\
         \frac{1}{3}\\
         0
          \end{bmatrix}s+\begin{bmatrix}
         \frac{-11}{3}\\
         \frac{5}{3}\\
         0
          \end{bmatrix}t=\begin{bmatrix}
         6\\
         1\\
         0
          \end{bmatrix}$

$x_1+0x_2+\frac{11}{3}s - \frac{11}{3}t = 6$; $x_1 = 6-\frac{11}{3}s+\frac{11}{3}t$

$0x_1+x_2+\frac{1}{3}s+\frac{5}{3}t = 1$; $x_2= 1- \frac{1}{3}s-\frac{5}{3}t$

$x_3=s$

$x_4=t$

Not sure, does this answer (b)?

Comment: From the first part, you should have found $b_3-b_2+\dfrac{1}{2}b_1$ (sign error?) in that last entry, which must be zero for there to be a solution, so we need $b_3-b_2+\dfrac{1}{2}b_1 = 0 \implies b_1 = 2 (b_2 - b_3)$

Comment: Now I am sure you have a sign error as I show above, cause for the second part, you should get $$
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 0 & \dfrac{11}{3} & -\dfrac{11}{3} & 6 \\
 0 & 1 & \dfrac{1}{3} & \dfrac{5}{3} & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$ This makes $x_3$ and $x_4$ free variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Row reduction of matrix**

Find the fundamental columns.

*Reorder* rows to simplify arithmetic.

$$
% E
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 0 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
% A
\left[
\begin{array}{crrr}
 0 & 6 & 2 & 10 \\
 1 & 1 & 4 & -2 \\
 1 & -2 & 3 & -7 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
=
% PA
\left[
\begin{array}{crrr}
 1 & -2 & 3 & -7 \\
 1 & 1 & 4 & -2 \\
 0 & 6 & 2 & 10 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
$$

*Clear* column 1:
$$
% E
\left[
\begin{array}{rcc}
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
% PA
\left[
\begin{array}{crrr}
 1 & -2 & 3 & -7 \\
 1 & 1 & 4 & -2 \\
 0 & 6 & 2 & 10 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
=
% A
\left[
\begin{array}{crcr}
 1 & -2 & 3 & -7 \\
 0 & 3 & 1 & 5 \\
 0 & 6 & 2 & 10 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
$$

*Clear* column 2:
$$
% E
\left[
\begin{array}{cc
c}
 1 & \frac{2}{3} & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
 0 & -2 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
% PA
\left[
\begin{array}{crcr}
 1 & -2 & 3 & -7 \\
 0 & 3 & 1 & 5 \\
 0 & 6 & 2 & 10 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
=
% A
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & \frac{11}{3} & -\frac{11}{3} \\
 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{5}{3} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
$$
Result
$$
%
\begin{align}
 \mathbf{A} &\mapsto \mathbf{E_{A}} \\
%
\left[
\begin{array}{crrr}
 0 & 6 & 2 & 10 \\
 1 & 1 & 4 & -2 \\
 1 & -2 & 3 & -7 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
 &\mapsto
%
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \boxed{1} & 0 & \frac{11}{3} & -\frac{11}{3} \\
 0 & \boxed{1} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{5}{3} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
\end{align}
%
$$
The boxed pivots reveal the fundamental columns: $1$ and $2$.

---

**(a)**
For a data vector $b$ to reside in the range space of the columns, it must be a linear combination of the fundamental columns:

$$
\boxed{
 b\in\mathcal{R}\left( \mathbf{A} \right) \quad \iff \quad b = 
 \alpha \left[
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
+
 \beta \left[
\begin{array}{r}
 6 \\
 1 \\
-2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
}
%
\tag{1}
$$
where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are arbitrary constants.

---

**(b)**
What are the restriction on $b_{1}$ so that the following vector resides in the range space of the columns?
$$
b=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 b_{1} \\
 \color{blue}{7} \\
 \color{blue}{4} \\
\end{array}
\right]
=
 \alpha \left[
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 \color{blue}{1} \\
 \color{blue}{1} \\
\end{array}
\right]
+
 \beta \left[
\begin{array}{r}
 6 \\
 \color{blue}{1} \\
\color{blue}{-2} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
There are a couple of ways to attack this problem, one of which is to solve the matrix equation
$$
%
\left[
\begin{array}{cr}
 \color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{1} \\
 \color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{-2} \\
\end{array}
\right]
%%
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 \alpha \\
 \beta \\
\end{array}
\right]
%%
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 \color{blue}{7} \\
 \color{blue}{4} \\
\end{array}
\right]
%%
$$

The solution is 
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 \alpha \\
 \beta \\
\end{array}
\right]
=
\frac{1}{3}
\left[
\begin{array}{cr}
 2 & 1 \\
 1 & -1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 7 \\
 4 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
=
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
 6 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Put the mixing constants into $(1)$
$$
 6 \left[
\begin{array}{c}
 0 \\
 1 \\
 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
+
 1 \left[
\begin{array}{r}
 6 \\
 1 \\
-2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
=
\left[
\begin{array}{r}
 6 \\
 7 \\
 4 \\
\end{array}
\right]
%
$$
This shows that
$$
\boxed{
 b_{1} = 6
}
$$